# Proper way to allow json with and without root node using spring mvc and jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/users/{userId}/settings", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = { "application/json" })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public UserSetting createUserSetting(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,
        @RequestBody Setting setting){
    return userSettingService.createSetting(userId, userSetting);
}
```

When invoking the url /v1/users/12345/settings POST

with the payload

```
{"Setting":{"name":"CoolSetting", "id":"SETTING-ID"}}
```

the method behaves as expected.

What I would also like to accept is:

```
{"name":"CoolSetting", "id": "SETTING-ID"}
```

how do I accept the second payload version without the root tag.

The object in question looks like this

```
public class Setting{
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    //getters and setters removed
}
```

how can I tell spring to marshel using either json method?

Comment: That almost looks like Jackson is not being used but jettison. As a test change the JSON property annotations to a different name then the java name.

Comment: I am pretty sure we are using jackson, but what do you mean change the JSON annotations to a different name @AdamGent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE property to achieve this result. For serialization use SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE.

Detailed explanation and usage available in this blog: [Jackson with and without root node](http://www.texient.com/2015/02/customizing-root-node-name-in-jaxb-jackson-json-processor.html)